# SQL Server 2012: dynamic SQL limitation ( > 4000 chars) (split)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this dynamic SQL in a stored procedure:

```
Declare @template nvarchar(max)
Declare @publishdetails nvarchar(max)

set @publishdetails= ',B.[PublishedBy]=suser_name(),
  B.[PublishedDate]=GETDATE() '

set @template='if NOT EXISTS(select * from ' +@DestinationDB+ '.[CLs] where id='+ str(@slid)+') 
insert into  ' +@DestinationDB+ '.CLs (id,slid,slversion) VALUES ( '+ str(@id)+','+ str(@slid)+','+str(@slversion)+')

update  B set 
      B.[Clientid]=A.clientid,
        --.........
      B.[CreatedDate] = A.CreatedDate,
      B.[ModifiedDate] = A.ModifiedDate,
      B.[CreatedBy] = A.CreatedBy,
      B.[ModifiedBy] = A.ModifiedBy '+@publishdetails+ --Added publishdetails
    'FROM  ' + @SourceDB + '.[CLs] as A, '+ @DestinationDB+ '.[CLs] as B
        where A.slversion = '+ str(@slversion)+' and A.id='+str(@slid) + 'B.slversion = '+ str(@slversion)+' and B.id='+str(@slid)

        print 'template is: ' + @template
exec sp_Executesql @template
```

When `exec sp_Executesql @template` is executing, it fails. Because `@template` is > 4000 chars and is truncated. How can I split it in chunks and execute it the correct way?

Comment: At first glance, it seems you are doing an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. You might be able to save some characters by changing the query to use the `MERGE` functionality instead. However, if you simply have a very long list of columns, there might just not be much you can really do. The limit for sp_executesql can indeed be a major pain when dealing with dynamic sql.

Comment: @SchmitzIT can you provide with a runable example of `MERGE` based on my sample code?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to split the text into parts. You do need to make sure that truncation doesn't occur whilst you're [concatenating strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql):

> If the result of the concatenation of strings exceeds the limit of 8,000 bytes, the result is truncated. However, if at least one of the strings concatenated is a large value type, truncation does not occur.

So, make sure that the first concatenation is working with a large value type (and thus produces a large value type as its result) and every subsequent concatenation should be saved from truncation:

```
set @template=CONVERT(nvarchar(max),'if NOT EXISTS(select * from ' ) + @DestinationDB + ...
```

(In this way, you don't have to insert conversions *everywhere*)

---

This generates an error:

```
declare @t nvarchar(max)

set @t = 'select LEN(''' + REPLICATE('A',3000) + REPLICATE('B',3000) + REPLICATE('C',3000) + ''')'

exec sp_executesql @t
```

And this produces the result 9000:

```
declare @t nvarchar(max)

set @t = CONVERT(nvarchar(max),'select LEN(''') + REPLICATE('A',3000) + REPLICATE('B',3000) + REPLICATE('C',3000) + ''')'

exec sp_executesql @t
```

Comment: tried that but the same error. I get syntax error because of the truncation of the @template

Comment: @aggicd - then there's some non-obvious from your question instance where other truncation is occurring - e.g. in the code in the question, all concatenations appear to be straightforward with no bracketing. If you have any bracketing then that mean the order of operations is different from left-to-right and so you'll have to apply the "first" conversion elsewhere.

Comment: Please check my edited post. There was a part of a code that I didn't include the first time. @publishdetails

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use this approach:

```
Declare @template nvarchar(max) = N''
set @template = @template +N'.... -- Or SELECT instead of SET
```

**Update#1**

I run this simple query on my test DB:

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = N'',
        @i int = 1

WHILE 1000 > @i
BEGIN
    SET @query = @query + N'SELECT @@version;'
    SET @i = @i+1
END

SELECT LEN (@query)

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

I got batch with length of 16983 characters. And execution goes well - no truncation. I guess the problem is inside `@SourceDB + '.[CLs]` and `@DestinationDB+ '.[CLs]` tables. Somewhere there you got data truncation.

Try to `PRINT` your query and run it manually.

Comment: tried that with no luck... again syntax error due to truncation

Comment: Can you post `print @template` results? Have you tried execute this batch?

Comment: What `SELECT LEN(@template)` shows? Have you tried `EXEC(@template)`?