# SQL Server dynamic SQL size exceed 4000 chars

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, nvarchar

In SQL Server I have dynamic sql query, but the size of the query is higher than 4000 chars.
Like in this post [SQL Server 2012: dynamic SQL limitation ( > 4000 chars) (split)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629908/sql-server-2012-dynamic-sql-limitation-4000-chars-split) there is no problem to manage with this issue.
But the problem is when I want to join string with variable.
For example, this works ok:

```
DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sqlQueryWhere NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sqlQuery =
    CONVERT(nvarchar(max),'SELECT
 .... '
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlQuery
```

But this sample doesn't work:

```
 DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);
 DECLARE @sqlQueryWhere NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sqlQueryWhere = CONVERT(nvarchar(max),' 1 = 1 ' )

SET @sqlQuery =
        CONVERT(nvarchar(max),'SELECT
     .... ' + @sqlQueryWhere + ' group by ... '
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlQuery
```

Comment: Try using `CONCAT` instead of `+`. It's way too easy to get accidental truncation with `+` if you're not religiously casting everything.

Comment: I have to assert that exceeding 4,000 characters with a dynamic sql statement is a pretty good indication that you need to take a hard look at what you are doing. More than likely there is a better approach to whatever it is you trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sample is wrong because you are converting *after* concatenation

Your concatenation is a series of short string that can't go above 4000 characters. That is. using `+` won't magically make the string more than 4000 characters

[I described it in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371383/for-nvarcharmax-i-am-only-getting-4000-characters-in-tsql/1371584#1371584)

This will work:

```
DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sqlQueryWhere NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sqlQueryBase NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sqlQueryGroupyBy NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sqlQueryWhere = N' 1 = 1 ' --already NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlQueryBase = N'SELECT
     .... '
SET @sqlQueryGroupyBy = N' group by ... '

SET @sqlQuery = CONCAT(@sqlQueryBase, @sqlQueryWhere @sqlQueryGroupyBy)

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

4000 characters is 4000 characters.  If I were breaking that limit, I'd look to aliasing the tables, creating views, or seeing if you can use some inline tables to help a bit.

Comment: No, when you use NVARCHAR(MAX) you can use longer string than 4000

Comment: Using `nvarchar(max)` actually made it shorter for me.